# What is the $2n$-th partial sum of a series produced by interleaving two geometric sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence
$$1, 1, 3, \frac{1}{3}, 9, \frac{1}{9}, 27, \frac{1}{27}, 81, \frac{1}{81},\dotsc.$$
What is the sum of the first $2n$ terms?

I divided this sequence into $2$ separate sequences with common ratios $1/3$ and $3$. Then found the sum of $2n$ terms of each divided sequence and summed them to get an expression in terms of $2n$. After rechecking my calculation I still couldn’t get the correct answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric progression is obtained by $$S = a_{0}\left(\frac{1 - r^{n}}{1 - r}\right)$$ where $a_{0}$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio. This will help simplify your work.

Comment: Remember, you should only sum the first $n$ terms of each of the two divided sequences, making $2n$ terms total. Maybe that's where you went wrong?

Comment: If I summed the first 2n terms of each sequence did I get an expression for sum of first 4n terms?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: As a concrete example, when $n = 3$,$$\underbrace{1 + 1 + 3 + \frac{1}{3} + 9 + \frac{1}{9}}_{2n = 6 \text{ terms}} = \underbrace{1 + 3 + 9}_{n = 3 \text{ terms}} + \underbrace{1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9}}_{n = 3 \text{ terms}}.$$

Comment: Yeah sum of the first n terms of each sequence and adding them together works

Comment: If sum of 2n terms is that then what will be the sum of n terms of that sequence?

Comment: @AnayChadha It depends.  Is $n$ even or odd?

Comment: If it depends then I would be happy to know what happens in both cases

Comment: Well, if $n$ is even, then it is of the form $2k$ for some positive integer $k$.  You seem to have that case figured out.  So what happens if $n$ is odd?  What would an odd number look like?  How would this compare to an even number?

Comment: The terms with common ratio 1/3 will always have the form Sn and the other sequence will have the same form but the one with common ratio 3 will have 1 more term than the sequence with common ratio 1/3.

Comment: Sn(common ratio 3)+ Sn-1(common ratio 1/3) both will have a =1